# No output showing after running a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, output

I have three java classes that construct nodes and implement several methods to manipulate a linked list. My node class contains a node. My node list class contains methods that manipulate the linked list. My link method builds a linked list, and my print method is suppose to print the linked list. I sort the linked list with a bubble sort method. When I call these 3 methods from my main method in the class list, no output shows in my console. I have tried everything but I haven't manage to print some output, and there are no error messages to indicate that something is wrong with my code.

Node class

```
public class iNode{
public int item;
public iNode next;

public iNode(int i, iNode n){ 
    item = i; 
    next = n; 
}
public iNode(int i){ 
    item = i; 
    next = null; 
}
// Node class
public int getItem() {
    return this.item;
}
```

Node list class

```
public class iNode_List {

public  static iNode head;
public static int size; 

public  iNode_List(){
    this.head = null;
    this.size = 0;
}

public static iNode link(int n, int m){

    iNode previous;
    iNode current;

    int i = 0;
    previous = null;
    while (i < n) {
        current = new iNode(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, m-1), previous);
        previous = current;
        head = current;
        i++;
    }
    return previous;
}

public static void print() {
    iNode currentNode = head;
    while(currentNode != null) {
        int data = currentNode.getItem();
        System.out.println(data);
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }

}

public static void Bubble_Sort (){
      if (size > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
                iNode currentNode = head;
                iNode next = head.next;
                for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
                    if (currentNode.item > next.item) {
                        int temp = currentNode.item;
                        currentNode.item = next.item;
                        next.item = temp;
                    } 
                    currentNode = next;
                    next = next.next;                   
                } 
            }
        }
}
```

List method

```
public class list {

public static void main (String [] args){
    iNode_List x = new iNode_List();
    x.link(10, 10);
    x.Bubble_Sort();
    x.print();

}
```

Comment: what is `list` in `x.list`?

Comment: Sorry i changed the naming of my method from list to link so that people would not get confused with the class name. I'll make an edit.

Comment: You made LinkedList so complex. I don't  know why. You will find so many example. First you need to understand, how to create a LinkedList datastructure and then print them. Then, try other things.

Comment: Assigment from school haha. Professors want to make everything more complex.

Comment: I would never make the `head` and `size` variables `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you never assign any value to `head`, but your method prints `head`, which is always null.  That's why nothing shows.

You probably want to add `head = current;` near the end of your `link` method.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I still can't get the bubble sort to work

Comment: It is not sorting the elements. But the output does print random integers.

Comment: Alan, now would probably be a good time to learn to use your debugger.  That way, you can step through your code and see the value of each variable after each step.  I'm sure you'll manage to find the problem fairly quickly.  If not, you can ask a separate Stack Overflow question.